# Google Maps API v3 disable all mouseover actions

Tags: api, dictionary, mouseover

I would like to stop the code popping up when someone mouses over a marker on the map. When clicked an infowindow appears as it should but I dont want the mouseover action.

Have tried this but it still happens:

`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });`

Is it possible to prevent all mouseover actions?
Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible . check map api v3 documentation mouse events

Comment: What exactly do you not want to happen?  Things like the title of a marker appearing while the client hovers over it?  Give some examples please.

Comment: I've scoured the Google docs and found nothing, hence my post here.  

Thanks for the reply, I dont want anything to happen on 'mouseover' the markers should be click activated only.

Comment: Not possible to disable mouseover events then?

Answer (score 1):

In [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType), Google introduced a new parameter to turn off the mouse wheel from zooming on your map, just add `scrollwheel: false` in mapOptions. here is an example:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: myLocation,
    zoom: 16,
    scrollwheel: false
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
```

That will prevent mouseover event to interrupt user scrolling web page.